# Run dynamically generated assembly in C (GNU/Linux)

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, jit, machine-code

I'm writing a proof-of-concept JIT compiler in C, which at the moment is generating strings of assembly code. The inline assembly functionality in C only deals with string literals that are known at compile time, so I can't use it to run my generated-at-runtime code.

I've read about using mmap() to execute generated *machine code* at runtime, but I'd like to avoid working with machine code if possible.

Does anyone know of any solutions? I've thought of writing it to a file and invoking the assembler & linker on said file, but that'd be messy and slow.

Comment: So you're saying you generate assembly source code? Why not just generate the machine code itself?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I'd prefer not to as it's less readable, harder to test, and time is of the essence so if I'd like to avoid refactoring if possible. Although it looks as if I may have to.

Comment: There is many lib out there for emitting assembly. [gnu-lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) [llvm](http://llvm.org/), ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ultimately to be "JIT" you need to be time sensitive which means generate machine code.  You might try putting in some debug code that generates both machine code to run and assembly code to verify, run the assembler compare the machine code from the assembly language to the machine code you generated directly and use that to debug/validate the machine code (if possible, sometimes assemblers want to do their own thing, not what you wanted them to do).

Comment: Generating both machine code to run, and assembly to debug/test against, is a great idea. I think this is what I will do. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is generate C/C++/Fortran code, compile it on the fly, link it into a DLL, and dynamically load the DLL, all of which takes on the order of a few seconds at most.
You could do the same, except generate ASM.
It's a very effective technique when you need speed of the resulting code, plus the flexibility of the code (and run-time libraries) of the language you're generating.

Comment: I've decided to go with the machine code option, but I find this to be a very interesting idea, I will be considering it for future projects. Are you aware of any relevant articles/tutorials etc?

Comment: @AlexJ136: Articles? The key things to learn are 1) how to write a DLL (any example will do), 2) how to "shell out" to run the compiler+linker under control of your program, and 3) how to load a DLL and get the procedure addresses it exports.